# Why is my VHDL counter not outputting pulses as desired?

Tags: counter, vhdl, fpga

I am working on creating a variable-frequency pulse train to control a motor, and am using the following code to generate pulses using a counter that counts up by some input increment value `inc_i`. I then pipe the MSB of the output of my counter, `dout_o[N-1]`, to an output pin on my FPGA. This should give me a 50% duty cycle square wave of the desired frequency, but I am just seeing a signal that starts low, goes high, and then never turns off again. Is there something obviously wrong with my code?

```
--****************************************************************************
-- Load required libraries
--****************************************************************************
library ieee;
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;

--****************************************************************************
-- Define the inputs, outputs, and parameters
--****************************************************************************
entity var_count is

    generic(N: integer :=32);               -- for generic counter size
    port(
            inc_i       : in    std_logic_vector(N-1 downto 0);
            load_i      : in    std_logic;
            clk_i       : in    std_logic;
            clear_i     : in    std_logic;
            clk_en_i    : in    std_logic;
            count_en_i  : in    std_logic;
            msb_o       : out   std_logic
        );

end var_count;

--****************************************************************************
-- Define the behavior of the counter
--****************************************************************************
architecture behavior of var_count is

    -- Define our count variable. No need to initialize in VHDL.
    signal count : unsigned(N-1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(0, N);
    signal incr  : unsigned(N-1 downto 0) := to_unsigned(0, N);

begin   
    -- Define our clock process
    clk_proc : process(clk_i, clear_i, load_i)
    begin
        -- Asynchronous clear
        if clear_i = '1' then
            count <= to_unsigned(0, N);
        end if;

        -- Asynchronous load
        if load_i = '1' then
            incr <= unsigned(inc_i);
        end if;

        -- Define processes synch'd with clock.
        if rising_edge(clk_i) and clk_en_i = '1' then
            if count_en_i = '1' then            -- increment the counter
                count <= count + incr;
            end if;
        end if;     
    end process clk_proc;

    -- Output the MSB for the sake of generating a nice easy square wave.
    msb_o <= count(count'left);

end behavior;
```

The square wave frequency should be given by the equation `pulse_freq = clock_freq * inc_i / 2^N` for an N-bit counter.

I am also trying to generate a single clock-cycle pulse by passing the MSB of my counter output (`msb_o(k)`) through a single-bit D-Q flip-flop to get `msb_o(k-1)` and then executing:

```
pulse = ~msb_o(k) * msb_o(k-1)
```

where `~` represents logical `NOT`, and `*` represents logical `AND`. This should give me a single clock-cycle pulse only when the counter rolls over. Neither this nor the MSB itself (50% duty cycle square wave) are showing when I read the output pin using an oscilloscope. Please let me know if you see any errors in my code.

Thank you for your help!

Reference that I used to put this together can be found [here](http://www.cs.uregina.ca/Links/class-info/301/counter/lecture.html), [here](http://esd.cs.ucr.edu/labs/tutorial/counter.vhd), and [here](http://www.synthworks.com/papers/vhdl_math_tricks_mapld_2003.pdf).

**EDIT 1:** I have updated the code in the question with suggestions that users have made. Now when I output the MSB of the counter, it goes high and never turns off again. I need to make the counter reset on overflow (which I have tried to do in the above). Any suggestions for how I can do this?

**EDIT 2:** I realized that since my increment value `inc_i` is not necessarily one, I may not be reaching a value of `2**N - 1` for rollover calculations. I therefore changed the rollover condition to:

```
if count > (2**N - unsigned(inc_i) - 1) then
    count <= to_unsigned(0, N);
```

I now seem to be getting pulses, but they are not exactly 50% duty cycle (which I think makes some sense) and they do not seem to change as expected when I change my increment value `inc_i`. Any idea why the rate is not changing?

**EDIT 3:** I realized that all I care about for my application is the MSB of the counter since that is what I will be using to either generate a 50% duty cycle square wave, or a pulse when it rolls over. In light of this, I replaced `dout_o` in the entity declaration with:

```
`msb_o : out std_logic`
```

and I replaced the  concurrent assignment statement at the end with:

```
msb_o <= '1' when count > (2**(N-1) - 1) else '0';
```

I am still getting very odd pulses that are not at all 50% duty cycle or necessarily the correct frequency. Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 4:** Updated my code with further changes. Also adding [this free book](http://www.freerangefactory.org/dl/free_range_vhdl.pdf) to the list of references.

**EDIT 5:** Updated my code to the (final) working edition.

Comment: Did the simulation work as expected?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I am not really sure how to make sense of the simulation since the overall program that this is used in is huge. I get a little lost in all of the logic signals. I will try to pick out the behavior of these signals in the simulation though and get back with results.

Comment: It is worth performing unit tests - maybe not on every component of a large project - but maybe most of them, and definitely key ones like this. A simple testbench can be used to stress the component in ways that would be difficult to arrange in a top level test, and get answers, usually faster than waiting for StackExchange posts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process does not adhere to general rules for a process to be recognized as
flip-flops by the synthesis tools, since the outer level for conditions does
not cover the signals in the process sensitivity list.  The synthesis tool has
probably given one or more warnings about this.

One way to rewrite the process to adhere to general rules for synthesizable
flip-flops is:

```
clk_proc : process (CLK)
begin
  if (CLK'event and CLK = '1') then
    if CLEAR = '1' then           -- clear the counter
      COUNT <= COUNT - COUNT;
    elsif CLK_EN = '1' then       -- increment the counter
      COUNT <= COUNT + INC;
    end if;
  end if;
end process clk_proc;
```

This places the check for clock edge at the outer level, and assumes that the
CLEAR is synchronous.

More nformation about VHDL coding style for registers is in for example
[Xilinx XST User Guide](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_5/xst_v6s6.pdf).

Your description of the single clock-cycle pulse looks OK, so the reason that
it does not work is probably derived from the above.

A larger rewrite of the module may be considered, in order to apply these
useful VHDL coding rules:

- Input and output ports are named with _i and _o, since this ease reading
  of code where the module is instantiated
- Signals without default value, since this may not work over all FPGA
  technologies
- Only upper case for constant identifiers, since this makes code reading
  easier.
- Don't use std_logic_unsigned, since this is Synopsys library and not VHDL
  standard
- Use rising_edge() for edge detection, for readability
- Use `(others => '0')` to clear, instead of `COUNT - COUNT`, since this works
  in simulation even if COUNT is all X's

Example in code below:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity var_count is
  port(
    inc_i    : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    clk_i    : in  std_logic;
    clear_i  : in  std_logic;
    clk_en_i : in  std_logic;
    dout_o   : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0));
end var_count;

architecture behavior of var_count is

  -- Define our count variable
  signal count : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

begin

  -- Define our clock process
  clk_proc : process (clk_i)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clk_i) then
      if clear_i = '1' then           -- clear the counter
        count <= (others => '0');
      elsif clk_en_i = '1' then       -- increment the counter
        count <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(count) + unsigned(inc_i));
      end if;
    end if;
  end process clk_proc;

  -- Concurrent assignment statement
  dout_o <= count;

end behavior;
```

If you are not already using a simulator, then ModelSim maybe a great
improvement to your toolbox.  Alera has [ModelSim-Altera Starter
Edition](http://www.altera.com/products/software/quartus-ii/modelsim/qts-modelsim-index.html)
that is free, and can be used for smal designs.

Comment: I have Quartus II v9.0 that I am programming in. I could simulate in this, but the overall program is so complicated that the simulation is somewhat meaningless to me. I have not put much time in to learning the simulator though. Thank you for your answer! I will work on applying changes and post my results.

Comment: One further question, will this automatically roll over when the counter maxes out? I need this to be the behavior.

Comment: @Engineero Simulation is *never* meaningless, more so for big designs. And yes, the counter will roll over.

Comment: IT is a simple task to simulate this module, you don't need the whole project for this. If you don't simulate your design, you are wasting lots of your time and over-complicate your problem.

Comment: Great, thanks @FarhadA for telling me that it is simple to simulate without any insight on how to do so. Anybody care to elaborate? I am not sure how I can separate this from my design and simulate it, and when I try to simulate it with the whole design, I am not getting anything. I am probably doing something wrong there with setting up my input file.

Comment: Well, in order to simulate a module, you need to create a simple test bench and a stimuli generating code. In your case, since you don't have that many signals, you just need to create a clock, set the enable to on and off and give it some random numbers and see how it behaves. I bet you will find your problems rather quickly.

Answer (score 2):

- There is no point in initialising a *signal*, if this signal will be a register, reset it to zero(or any other required value) and make sure your design starts in a reset state.
- Your clocked process was not sensitive to `CLEAR`, which is read in the process. I assume that you want an asynchronous CLEAR.
- std_logic_vectors cannot be added directly using `IEEE.numeric_std.all`, which is recommended for compatibility across different tools.
- There is no point in doing `COUNT-COUNT` for reseting the register when you can just drive them all to zeroes using `(others => '0')`.

See the code below.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


entity VAR_COUNT is

port(
        INC     : in    std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
        CLK     : in    std_logic;
        CLEAR   : in    std_logic;
        CLK_EN  : in    std_logic;
        DOUT    : out   std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );

end VAR_COUNT;

architecture behavior of VAR_COUNT is

-- Initialising a signal has no effect in hardware
signal COUNT:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := x"00_00_00_00";

-- Define our clock process, your clocked process was not senstive to CLEAR
begin clk_proc:process(CLK,CLEAR)
    begin
        if CLEAR = '1' then         -- clear the counter
            COUNT <= (others=>'0'); --always use this to reset
        elsif CLK_EN = '1' then     -- increment the counter
            if (CLK'EVENT AND CLK = '1') then
                COUNT <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(COUNT) + unsigned(INC));
            end if;
        end if;     
    end process clk_proc;

-- concurrent assignment statement
DOUT <= COUNT;

end behavior;
```

Comment: Just a note for the text bullets: * CLEAR need not be included in the sensitivity list of the process if CLEAR is used as synchronous signal, and not as asynchronous clear.  * std_logic_vectors can indeed be added directly if IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all is used, since this overloads + operator for std_logic_vector arguments.